# Why are the indices of a sparse non-diagonal array inversed?

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix file, which contains 820 lines. Sample of few lines of the file are as follows:

```
0   547 1

1   547 1

2   539 0.500000

2   540 0.500000

3   512 0.333333

3   515 0.333333
```

I want to import this sparse matrix file into Matlab. The full matrix contained in the file has 1184 rows and an equal numbers of columns. To convert this file into sparse matrix, I use the following commands:

```
T = reshape(T,3,entries)';
    disp('Array is: ');
    A = (sparse(T(:,1)+1, T(:,2)+1, T(:,3), rows , cols));
```

Firstly and before add +1 to index, an error is displayed, which is:

> "??? Error using ==> sparse Index into matrix must be positive.

It was due to Matlab begins at index 1, not at index 0.

After adding +1, the problem is resolved.
But now, iwhenI run this code

```
  A = (sparse(T(:,1)+1, T(:,2)+1, T(:,3), rows , cols));
```

For a diagonal matrix, the output is excellent, and the problem with the positive index is resolved. But when I try it for a nondiagonal matrix the result is that it inverses the output. I mean that instead of having (1, 500) = 3,67 it gives me (500,1) = 3,67. Why does Matlab do that?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a problem, as after that i want to compute the inversed array and the solution isn't the desirable. Do you think there is an error with  my code?

Comment: @Obito, if you spend your time correcting official program names, at least use [MATLAB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) correctly.

Comment: @Adriaan Cool, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably following row-major (e.g. your matrix was created in C) and MATLAB is column-major. To convert from one to the other, just swap the coordinates!

`A = (sparse(T(:,2)+1, T(:,1)+1, T(:,3), cols, rows));`

---

Example that it works:

```
T=[0   547 1;

1   547 1;

2   539 0.500000;

2   540 0.500000;

3   512 0.333333;

3   515 0.333333];

% choosen randombly 4x600 because I dont have the full matrix.
% Just use rows and cols in your case
    A = sparse(T(:,1)+1, T(:,2)+1, T(:,3), 4 , 600); % this one is as in C
    B = sparse(T(:,2)+1, T(:,1)+1, T(:,3), 600 , 4); % this one is my suggestion

isequal(A',B) %the transpose of A is equal to B
```

Comment: According to your direction, the problem still remains unfortunately.

Comment: @EviPanayiotara what do you mean? If you do `A(1,500)` you get the same thing using my code or yours? that is impossible.

Comment: Using the coorection you have suggested me:

Comment: A = (sparse(T(:,2)+1, T(:,1)+1, T(:,3), cols, rows));

Comment: @EviPanayiotara edited to prove that it indeed gives the transpose.

Comment: @AnderBiguri If I understand correctly, you should modify "To convert from one to the other...", since in the other way `+1` must change to `-1`, right?

Comment: @erfan ? No. I don't understand. Row/column major has nothing to do with the +1. the +1 is only to change from zero index to 1 index.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I mean `+1` here appears because in MATLAB indexing starts from one, while in C it starts from zero, am I wrong? If so, this formula works in one way. the opposite transform (MATLAB -> C) should have `-1` instead!

Comment: @erfan That  looks like it makes sense, but if you think it a bit further, it really doesn't. I am writing MATLAB code, to import from C. If I add a -1 there, there is no way it will work, the whole rest of the code is MATLAB code. I am not writting a whole C function to get MATLAB indexes and pass them to C, thats not even in the OPs question.

Comment: @AnderBiguri It was my misunderstanding! I thought by "To convert from one to the other..." you mean to make the data MATLAB- or C-compatible..!